# how to sort dates in Apache PIG?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a text file containing following dates in `yyyy-month-days` format in `dates.txt`

```
1999-01-20
2000-09-22
1995-06-10
2001-11-23

A = LOAD 'dates.txt' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (date:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS date;
```

Now I want to sort these dates using APACHE PIG. I am stuck up at this point.

Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would sort any other type.

```
C = order B by date;
dump C;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query.Hope it helps

```
A = LOAD 'dates.txt' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (date:chararray);
B = FOREACH A {
x=(date)ToDate(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
Generate ToUnixTime(x) as unixDTime,x as dateTime};
C=order B by unixDTime;

grunt>>dump C;
```

Ordering dateTime will throw joda time error on executing map reduce job.